# Google Chrome update seems to have broken my AutoHotKey scripts to expand text and automate other tasks

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

A restart of Chrome, this morning, seems to have 'broken' my autohotkey scripts to expand text messages and automate repetitive button pressing sequences.

I edit Waze maps and take part in various zooniverse projects.
For map editing, I had a bunch of phrases that I typed over and over.
I created 4 character strings that expand to types stuff like:
xttc expands to 'time to close.' 
All of that stopped working this morning. 
I use alt-A, to flicker between views on zooniverse.org's asteroid hunting task.
All of those are now non-functional if chrome is the 'focus'.

Very frustrating! Many hours of work writing scripts are now worthless unless I can figure out which setting to change.

Comment: If you could post some samples of the code it would be helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: The code doesn't matter much but here is a snippit from a script:

Comment: It won't let me send even a short snip, says it is too long.

Comment: Upload it to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and post a link

Comment: you can download from here.  http://goo.gl/vSohqK

Comment: I can't say I understand much of that code, but I can't see anything that shouldn't work in Chrome. Is the entire script dead or only certain things?

Comment: It should work in chrome. It was working in chrome yesterday.

Comment: for example I could type xttc and as soon as I hit the space bar, it would replace with the text. Now, nothing happens if I am using chrome as my browser. In other browsers, it works fine or even in notepad.

Comment: It is as if Chrome suddenly started intercepting all events and preventing other apps that are running from seeing them as long as chrome is the selected app.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new script with a single hotstring to test if that works at all in Chrome? I'm running `Version 38.0.2125.111 m (64-bit)` and AHK hotstrings work fine.

Comment: Version 38.0.2125.111 m  SciTE4AutoHotkey
Version 3.0.06.01 - Based on SciTE 3.5.1

Comment: currently running directly in the ahk editor   so I can do debug mode.  Usually use a compiled version of my scripts.

Comment: I guess I am going to have to reboot my latitude e6510 and see it that fixes it.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: rebooting seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks for all that commented.

Comment: I don't know why my 'id' changed when I logged in, nor why I can't give Sidola credit for helping me.